# Saving nested many-to-one model in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have troubles saving new `Child` in many-to-one relation using rest framework in Django. For some reason the problem only appears while creating a new record, not while editing existing one.

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    name_parent = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Child(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, related_name="children")
    name_child = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class ParentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Parent
        fields = ('id', 'name_parent')

class ChildSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Child
        fields = ('id', 'parent', 'name_child')
        depth = 1
```

When I didn't have `depth = 1` in `ChildSerializer` I could successfully add a new child using the following json:

```
{"id":"new", "name_child":"child", "parent":1}
```

Now with the `depth` in place the above throws `"non_field_errors": ["Invalid data"]`, while the following throws `{"parent": ["This field cannot be null."]}`:

```
{"id":"new", "name_child":"child", "parent":{"id":1, "name_parent":"parent"}}
```

(This json works fine for editing if I pass some id value instead of `new`)

Comment: This might help [`Creating nested objects`](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/django-rest-framework/Du_PbXe6crQ/Wj9u7ExhLkQJ)